# Problems with database Query when looking for a String

Tags: android, database, sqlite

`enter code here`I am trying to write a query to extract all rows in my Android SQLite database table where the location reference = "a string".  I am using the following code in my database helper class:

```
public Cursor fetchComponentsForLocation(String locationRef) {
    Cursor mCursor =
            rmDb.query(true, LOCATIONS_TABLE, new String[] {
                    LOCATION_ID, RUN_LINK, AREA_LINK, INSPECTION_LINK, LOCATION_REF, RACKING_SYSTEM, COMPONENT, POSITION, RISK, ACTION_REQUIRED, NOTES_GENERAL, MANUFACTURER, TEXT1, TEXT2, TEXT3, TEXT4, NOTES_SPEC}, 
                    LOCATION_REF + "=" + locationRef, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
}
```

And I call it in my activity as follows:

```
    // Get a Cursor for the list items
    Cursor listComponentCursor = rmDbHelper.fetchComponentsForLocation(locationRef);
    startManagingCursor(listComponentCursor);           

    // set the custom list adapter     
    setListAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, listComponentCursor));
```

Which then gets used in my ListAdapter to fill my list view.  Now in my other activities, when I am fetching rows based on the id (i.e. a long), this code works fine.  When I try it with String I get the following error:

*`Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: **no such column: g:** , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, run_link, area_link, inspection_link, location_reference, racking_system, component, position, risk, action_required, notes_general, manufacturer, text1, text2, text3, text4, notes_spec FROM location_table WHERE location_reference=g`*

As you can see, in this case the String = 'g', but it seems to looking for a column called 'g' instead of looking at the data!

Very confused why this works with long but not String.  Help appreciated as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a couple of single quotes around the string you are searching for:

```
LOCATION_REF + "='" + locationRef+"'", null,
```

Comment: Fantastic - thanks for your help.  Obvious when you know!! :)

Answer (score 3):

Change yours with this:

```
String[] columns = {LOCATION_ID, RUN_LINK, AREA_LINK, 
                    INSPECTION_LINK, LOCATION_REF, RACKING_SYSTEM, COMPONENT,
                    POSITION, RISK, ACTION_REQUIRED, NOTES_GENERAL, MANUFACTURER, TEXT1, TEXT2, TEXT3, TEXT4, NOTES_SPEC};
String[] selection = LOCATION_REF + "= ?";

Cursor c = rmDb.query(true, LOCATIONS_TABLE, columns, selection, new String[] {locationRef},
                    null, null, null, null);
```

I recommend to you use **placeholders**. This way is cleaner and much more safe.

Comment: Thank you deceiver - I will look through my code and revise where necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The where should look like `LOCATION_REF + "='" + locationRef + "'"` as the strings in the query should be inclused with `''`

Comment: Thank you for responding. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

use this line

```
rmDb.query(true, LOCATIONS_TABLE, new String[] {
                LOCATION_ID, RUN_LINK, AREA_LINK, INSPECTION_LINK, LOCATION_REF, RACKING_SYSTEM, COMPONENT, POSITION, RISK, ACTION_REQUIRED, NOTES_GENERAL, MANUFACTURER, TEXT1, TEXT2, TEXT3, TEXT4, NOTES_SPEC}, 
                LOCATION_REF + "='" + locationRef+"'", null,
                null, null, null, null);
```

actually `LOCATION_REF` if of type `String`, so you need to put commas there. SQLite Convention.